# Checkboxes in dropdown does not have checked class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, marionette

I have a very complex dropdown menu with numerous controls in it. Because of this I need to have `e.stopPropagation()` in my click event of the dropdown container.

This all worked fine; when a user selects anything in the dropdown, it remains open. The problem is with checkboxes and radio buttons. When a user selects them, in the UI they have it marked as checked but the code does not add the `checked` class to it. So when I want to retrieve all the checked items from the dropdown, it returns an empty list.

I am assuming this happens because of the click event on the dropdown. I know I can override the click events of the check boxes to manually add the checked class but this isn't very good for expanding the dropdown in the future.

I am using Marionette Views to build the dropdown.

UPDATE:

I removed the e.stopPropagation() and it still doesn't have a checked class in the html, even though in the UI the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just select the checked check-boxes instead of searching for 'checked' class. Try this:

```
$('#checkbox_container_id').find(':checkbox:checked');
```

Comment: Doesn't that depend on whether the checkbox has a checked class or not?

Comment: I tried this - `this.ui.checkbox.find(":checkbox:checked")` and it returns an empty list

Answer (score 0):

Another option - can you just toggle a CSS class to the checkbox/radio buttons when they are selected?

I had a scenario a couple weeks ago where a user should be able to select multiple states. Here's how I ended up tracking that:

```
    events:
      "click .state": "stateSelected"
      "click .saveStates": "saveStates"

    saveStates: (e) ->
        if @state != ""
            @model.set(state: @state, demographic: true)
            $('#stateButton').addClass("selected")
        else
            @model.set(state: null)
            $('#stateButton').removeClass("selected")

    stateSelected: (e) ->
            @email = @model.get('email')
            $(e.currentTarget).toggleClass("selected")
            if e.currentTarget.classList[1] == "selected"
                if @state != ""
                    @state = @state + "|" + e.currentTarget.textContent.toLowerCase()
                else
                    @state = e.currentTarget.textContent.toLowerCase()
            else
                state = @state.split("|")
                state.splice(state.indexOf(e.currentTarget.textContent.toLowerCase()), 1)
                stateRequirements = ""
                state.forEach (requirements) ->
                    if stateRequirements != ""
                        stateRequirements = stateRequirements + "|" + requirements.toLowerCase()
                    else 
                        stateRequirements = requirements.toLowerCase()

                @state = stateRequirements  

            if e.currentTarget.textContent == "Select All"
                e.currentTarget.textContent = "Unselect All"
                $(".state").addClass("selected")
                states = ""
                $(".state").each (state) ->                     
                    if $(this).text() != "Unselect All"
                        if states != ""
                            states = states + "|" + $(this).text().toLowerCase() 
                        else
                            states = $(this).text().toLowerCase()

                @state = states
            else if e.currentTarget.textContent == "Unselect All"
                e.currentTarget.textContent = "Select All"
                $(".state").removeClass("selected")
                @state = ""
```

Hopefully that helps a little with the general idea.